# Process opus audio stream in Javascript to find volume

Tags: javascript, opus, vorbis

I'm writing a program in Javascript and I've managed to get an opus audio stream working but I need to find the volume from this stream.
Anyone got any ideas on how this could be done?

Thanks :)

Comment: Don't think that opus stream know anything about volume levels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get the decibel level of an audio in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123525/how-do-you-get-the-decibel-level-of-an-audio-in-javascript)